# Run and Close a ros package inside python program

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a python program that has a GUI.

I want when a user clicks on a button to execute a ROS package. Also, I have another button, when the user clicks, I want to close the running package.

I do not know how to do that.

I know how to open the program:

```
    # calibration command
        calib_command_str = "rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size {}x{} {} {} --square {} right:={} left:={} left_camera:={} right_camera:={}".format(interior_corner_hor_axis, interior_corner_ver_axis, camera_service_check_value, approx_str, square_len, right_camera_image_topic, left_camera_image_topic, left_camera_image_super_topic, right_camera_image_super_topic)
    
        os.system(calib_command_str)
```

However, I do not how to close it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/404163/run-and-close-a-ros-package-inside-python-program/) by [farhad-bat](https://answers.ros.org/users/108560/farhad-bat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2022-07-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS, [killing a node is as follows](http://wiki.ros.org/rosnode#rosnode_kill)

```
rosnode kill node_name
```

What the `rosnode kill` does is send a `SIGINT` to the NodeHandle, and what the node should do is deconstruct its classes and free the NodeHandle (in correctly written code).

You can use `os.system` with it too.

For Custom `SIGINT` Handler (in C++) you can use this tutorial:

- http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Initialization%20and%20Shutdown#Shutting_Down

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-07-25**:
If this answers your question, you can mark it as correct, so it will be visible in the question queue :)